# Python - How combine three arrays and outpot as one json file

Tags: python, json

(I am new in Python. I use Jupyter also to do some coding)

There are three arrays prepared as below: (sample data)

```
first= {}
second= {}
third= {}

first[1] = [[11, 111], [110,1010], [111,1010]]
first[2] = [12, 222]
first[3] = [[13, 333], [130, 1303]]

second[1] = [21, 211]
second[2] = [22, 222]
second[3] = [[23, 333], [230, 2303]]

third[1] = [31, 311]
third[2] = [[32, 222], [310,1030], [311,3010]]
third[3] = [33, 333]
```

And executing the below as an example:

```
type(third), third
```

the output is:

> (dict, {1: [31, 311], 2: [[32, 222], [310, 1030], [311, 3010]], 3:
> [33, 333]})

What I need to have the below output:

```
    allarrays={} (or something else)
    
    allarrays={"list1": {"1": [[11, 111], [110, 1010], [111, 1010]], "2": [12, 222], 
"3": [[13, 333], [130, 1303]]}}, "list2": {"1": [21, 211], "2": [22, 222], 
"3": [[23, 333], [230, 2303]]}, "list3": {"1": [31, 311], "2": [[32, 222], [310, 1030], [311, 3010]], 
"3": [33, 333]}}
```

The steps and changes are:

1- add this string **"list1"** or **"list2"** or **"list3"**  at the start of each array

```
first = "list1" + first (does not work)
```

2- then make this {"list1": {**"1"**:... ("1" should be in quotations)

```
I do not know how to put it in quotations
```

3- combine the tree into one array or string

```
allarrays = first + second + third 
gives this error: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'dict' and 'dict'
```

4- save them into a json file

```
import json
with open("result.json", 'w') as fp:
    json.dump(allarrays, fp)
```

Comment: Did you just gave us a sample of your data or this is actually your data ? Because you already have what you need (allarrays) ?

Comment: @BcK It is a sample data. The real data is produced differently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just a simple example.

Inflexible code.

Then you should change it yourself.

```
first = {}
second = {}
third = {}

first[1] = [[11, 111], [110, 1010], [111, 1010]]
first[2] = [12, 222]
first[3] = [[13, 333], [130, 1303]]

second[1] = [21, 211]
second[2] = [22, 222]
second[3] = [[23, 333], [230, 2303]]

third[1] = [31, 311]
third[2] = [[32, 222], [310, 1030], [311, 3010]]
third[3] = [33, 333]

total = [first, second, third]

allarrays = {}

result = {'list1': {'1': [[11, 111], [110, 1010], [111, 1010]],
                    '2': [12, 222],
                    '3': [[13, 333], [130, 1303]]},
          'list2': {'1': [[11, 111], [110, 1010], [111, 1010]],
                    '2': [12, 222],
                    '3': [[13, 333], [130, 1303]]},
          'list3': {'1': [[11, 111], [110, 1010], [111, 1010]],
                    '2': [12, 222],
                    '3': [[13, 333], [130, 1303]]}}


for index, item in enumerate(total):
    _ = dict()
    for k, v in item.items():
        _.update({str(k): v})
    allarrays.update({f'list{index + 1}': _})


print(allarrays)
print(result == allarrays)
```

Comment: Thank you. Only one problem. < "list1": {"1" > are double quotations. The output is not like this. This is output of your codes: < {'list1': {'1': >

Comment: This is just a simple example and `print(result == allarrays)` `ouptut = True`, the following program should be changed by yourself

Comment: Json will automatically convert `'` to `"`

Comment: You don't need to deal with it, just `json.dump` directly

Comment: If you want to convert to json you should `json.dump(allarrays, open("result.json", 'w'))`

Answer (score 0):

dit={}

l=[first,second,third]

for index,i in enumerate(l):

```
   keys=list(i.keys())
   for p in keys:
       i[f"{p}"]=i[p]
       k=i.pop(p)
   dit[f"list{index+1}"]=i
```

print(dit)

Comment: Thank you. Your codes is also right but with the same problem as the above answer. < "list1": {"1" > are double quotations. The output is not like this. This is output of your codes: < {'list1': {'1': >